# Custom taxonomy forms for user profile

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, profiles, register-taxonomy

I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) made by Justin Tadlock .

I can't update profile, it doesn't save to user profile :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_profession_tax' );
$post_type = get_post_type();
function create_profession_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'profession',
        '$post_type',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Profession' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'profession' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}


function my_update_profession_count( $terms, $taxonomy ) {
    global $wpdb;

    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {

        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );

        do_action( 'edit_term_taxonomy', $term, $taxonomy );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, compact( 'count' ), array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term ) );
        do_action( 'edited_term_taxonomy', $term, $taxonomy );
    }
}

/* Adds the taxonomy page in the admin. */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_add_profession_admin_page' );


function my_add_profession_admin_page() {

    $tax = get_taxonomy( 'profession' );

    add_users_page(
        esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
        esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
        $tax->cap->manage_terms,
        'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax->name
    );
}



/* Create custom columns for the manage profession page. */
add_filter( 'manage_edit-profession_columns', 'my_manage_profession_user_column' );


function my_manage_profession_user_column( $columns ) {

    unset( $columns['posts'] );

    $columns['users'] = __( 'Users' );

    return $columns;
}

/* Customize the output of the custom column on the manage professions page. */
add_action( 'manage_profession_custom_column', 'my_manage_profession_column', 10, 3 );


function my_manage_profession_column( $display, $column, $term_id ) {

    if ( 'users' === $column ) {
        $term = get_term( $term_id, 'profession' );
        echo $term->count;
    }
}

function my_save_user_profession_terms( $user_id ) {

    $tax = get_taxonomy( 'profession' );

    /* Make sure the current user can edit the user and assign terms before proceeding. */
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) && current_user_can( $tax->cap->assign_terms ) )
        return false;

    $term = esc_attr( $_POST['profession'] );

    /* Sets the terms (we're just using a single term) for the user. */
    wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, array( $term ), 'profession', false);

    clean_object_term_cache( $user_id, 'profession' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'profession', $_POST['profession'] );
}

/* Add section to the edit user page in the admin to select profession. */
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_edit_user_profession_section' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_edit_user_profession_section' );


function my_edit_user_profession_section( $user ) {

$tax = get_taxonomy( 'profession' );

/* Make sure the user can assign terms of the profession taxonomy before proceeding. */
if ( !current_user_can( $tax->cap->assign_terms ) )
    return;

/* Get the terms of the 'profession' taxonomy. */
$terms = get_terms( 'profession', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) ); ?>

<h3><?php _e( 'Profession' ); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">

<tr>
<th><label for="profession"><?php _e( 'Select Profession' ); ?></label></th>

<td><?php

/* If there are any profession terms, loop through them and display checkboxes. */
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<input type="radio" name="profession" id="profession-<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" <?php checked( true, is_object_in_term( $user->ID, 'profession', $term ) ); ?> /> <label for="profession-<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></label> <br />
<?php }
}

/* If there are no profession terms, display a message. */
else {
_e( 'There are no professions available.' );
}

?></td>

</tr>
    <tr><?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </tr>

</table>
<?php }

/* Update the profession terms when the edit user page is updated. */
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_user_profession_terms' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_user_profession_terms' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :

- bad order in function make a mess between variables **my_save_user_profession_terms** is before **my_edit_user_profession_section** and should be the **oppposite**
- I'm calling **$term** outside the **foreach**

Now it works !